# Create a form having fields for users which on submit give permissions to the different users

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, infopath, csom

My scenario is i have to create a new company(document library) and each company has different users each having specific permissions.

**NOTE:** when creating a new company,we have a directors field and an accountant field,when submitting the form each of these users should get a different permissions to access files automatically.

NOW,In each company(document library) i need to create some document sets based on the company type AUTOMATICALLY when i submit the form. Found that a custom form can be created via infopath,which later found is going to be deprecated i wanted to know how to proceed as i am still a beginner,i had some look at csom and webhook but unfortunately webhook is not the best approach as far i could guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can create form in SharePoint using out of box feature of Share Point. Please follow below steps:

**Step 1:** Create a custom List with your desired column like Questions-Single line of text

**Step 2:** Your New form is visible by clicking New Item in the list tool bar.

**Step 3:** If required you can put validation on field also using List settings.

Please refer the following article

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-form-that-has-restricted-permission-8ED44DBD-3945-4F1A-B2E6-DEA8E97435B4

https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/2592376/manage-permissions-and-control-access-to-sharepoint-designer

Comment: what i meant is in the form i will have a field for directors,a field for accountant and based on it i have to set permissions automatically for those users when i submit the form and allow them to access only the document sets they have rights to. AND NOTE each users have separate permissions but can only see files(which they have access to based on their roles)in the company they are.NOTE ALSO : all the users are external users

Comment: i edited the question